# Flutter passed arguments return null allways

Tags: flutter, dart

In this simple flutter [GitHub](https://github.com/Seanmcn/flutter-nav-params/) repository implementation we have a simple screen which we want to pass arguments and getting them in destination screen, for example

form `ScreenA()` we want pass arguments to `ScreenB()`

defined routes:

```dart
routes: {
  '/page/one': (context) => ScreenA(),
  '/page/two': (context) => ScreenB(),
  '/page/three': (context) => ScreenC(),
},
```

fist of all we have `ScreenA()`:

```dart
class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Navigation with params'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child:  ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Click me!'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              '/page/two',
              arguments: PageArguments(
                  id: 1,
                  title: "Example Title"
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and destination page as `ScreenB()` is:

```dart
class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;

    /* getting currect route name */
    print(ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name);

    /* getting NULL arguments */
    print(arguments);

    return Scaffold();
  }
}

class PageArguments{
  final int id;
  final String title;
  PageArguments({required this.id, required this.title});
}
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: @DineshNagarajan i read before submitting question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar package does not pass correctly route information, it [could be a bug](https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/issues/213). If you put a breakpoint in the `build` method of `ScreenB`, you will see that not only the argument is null, but route name is also wrong.

I tried in `main.dart` with `onGenerateRoute` and it worked for me this way:

```
  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          title: 'Home',
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
              initialRoute: '/page/one',
              onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                WidgetBuilder builder;
                // Manage your route names here
                switch (settings.name) {
                  case '/page/one':
                    builder = (BuildContext context) => ScreenA();
                    break;
                  case '/page/two':
                    builder = (BuildContext context) => ScreenB();
                    break;
                  default:
                    throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
                }
                return MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: builder,
                  settings: settings,
                );
              })),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(title: 'Help', icon: Icon(Icons.help)),
    ];
  }
```

About casting the argument, I agree with the other answer.

Comment: Welcome. About the bug (if it is a bug) you can contact the package author.

Answer (score 0):

**Main and MyApp for reference**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ScreenA(),
      routes: {
        '/page/one': (context) => ScreenA(),
        '/page/two': (context) => ScreenB(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Update ClassB with below code no modification required in ClassA**

```
class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final arguments =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as PageArguments;

    print(ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name);
    print(arguments.id);
    print(arguments.title);
    print("------");

    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

**Key update:**

Typecasting the argument.

```
final arguments =
    ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as PageArguments;
```

**Console log:**

[image]

Comment: It works with normal route definition, but not with `persistent_bottom_nav_bar` package.

Comment: I see since no reference to this package in question I was not aware of it. Thanks @PeterKoltai