# flutter error : A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

error on this line `data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`

```
class WorldTime {

  String location; //location name for UI
  late String time; //the time in location
  String flag;  //url to an asset flag icon
  String url;  //location url for api endpoint

  WorldTime({required this.location, required this.flag, required this.url});

   Future<void> getTime() async{

     try{
       
       //make the request
       Response response = await get(Uri. parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
       Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

       //print(data);

       //get properties from data
       String datetime = data['datetime'];
       String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);
       
       //create datetime object
       DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
       now = now.subtract(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));

       // set the time property
       time = now.toString();
     }
     catch(e){
       print('caught error : $e');
       time = 'could not get time data';
     }
  }
}
```

using that class object here

```
void setupWorldTime() async {
WorldTime x =WorldTime(location: 'kolkata', flag: 'g.png', url: '/Asia/Kolkata');
await x.getTime();
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home',arguments: {
  'location' : x.location,
  'flag' : x.flag,
  'time' : x.time,
});
```

}

i'm trying to pass a map using `pushReplacementNamed();`

```
Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Comment: There's more code you have to share, are you using firebase?

Comment: check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780877/2804581

Comment: no I'm not using firebase, an api called worldtime api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a class for the arguments:

```
class MyArguments {
  String? myString;
  int? myInt;
  MyArguments(this.myString, this.myInt);
}
```

2. Pass values like this for example:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  '/route',
  arguments: MyArguments("a",1),
);
```

3. Use it the target widget's builder:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as MyArguments;
    // do something with args.myString, args.myInt
```

Comment: `final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as MyArguments;` will do the magic than using dynamic.

Comment: i did not use a class and as Myarguments but why does using `final data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;` remove the error?

Comment: Check [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html), the method `pushReplacementNamed` needs `arguments` as type `Object?`, and what you give it to, is `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`, that's what causes the error.

Comment: With your syntax you arguments would be an object in JavaScript, but not in Dart.

Comment: So the point is, you have to use a Dart object as arguments, and therefore you have to define a class, as I wrote in the answer. Check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) as well.